# OpenSubtitles API 401 Unauthorized how to fix?

Tags: php, xml-rpc, subtitle

I'm trying to fetch subtitles from OpenSubtitles (http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC) like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//Opensubtitles listing
function data($request){
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\nUser-Agent: PHPRPC/1.0\r\n",
    'content' => $request
    )));

    $server = 'http://api.opensubtitles.org/xml-rpc'; // api url
    $file = file_get_contents($server, false, $context);

    $response = xmlrpc_decode($file);
    return $response;
}

//Get token
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("LogIn", array('', '', 'eng', 'TemporaryUserAgent'));
$token = data($request)['token'];
//Get listing
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("SearchSubtitles", array(
    'imdb' => '0462499',
    'sublanguageid' => 'eng',
    'season' => '',
    'episode' => '',
    'token' => $token
));
$response = data($request);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

However I keep getting 401 Unauthorized. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I know it's not a problem with the API because I am able to retrieve the token just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your username/password instead empty string.

And change UserAgent in TemporaryUserAgent in Header as written in
http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/DevReadFirst

Answer (score 0):

The second request should be in the following format:-

```
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request("SearchSubtitles", array($token, array(array('sublanguageid' => 'eng', 'imdbid' => 'your_imdbid'))));
```

Hope this helps.